# Derivation of the fundamental principle in the mechanics of beams

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-analysis, applied-mechanics, beam

Can someone provide the derivation for the following equation:

$$\int_l Q_Z(x) dx = M_y (x) \tag1$$

or equivalently :

$$\frac{dM_y}{dx}=Q_Z\tag2.$$

I am interested in the $1D$ isotropic material version.

[image]

*Appendix*

When drawing the [shear and moment diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_and_moment_diagram) for this case, we would get something like this:
[image]

Since the $Q_z$ is positive, the slope of $M_y$ has to be positive, because of equation $(2).$

But if $M_y$ has to have a positive slope and has to be zero at the free end, than it has to look like in the picture, i.e. it has to have a negative value.

Can that be a priori recognized from the equation $(1)$ or is it just a convention that when a beam curves downwards that it will be negative, and when it curves upwards, it will be positive, like explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_and_moment_diagram)?

Comment: Draw a free body diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just integrate and evaluate  $x$ from $0$ to $l$.

$$\int_l Q_Z(x) dx = Q_z(x) \ x\biggr\rvert _o^l = Q_z(x)l= M_y(x)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just added an appendix to my question, can you please confirm if my reasoning is correct?

Comment: @User198, yes it is a convention. bending moment is positive when it  is acting anticlockwise to the right of section.